# How to make 3 columns in 1 cell in HTML table

Tags: html, reactjs

How to create 3 columns in 1 cell of HTML table like in this image below created from Excel.

[image: Excel table]

I tried to use unlist method as subtitute but it looks ugly on my table.

[image: My hard coded table]

I'm using react js and material UI to recreate the table from excel.

```
<TableContainer component={Paper}>
    <Table sx={{ width: "100%" }} aria-label="customized table">
      <TableHead>
        <TableRow>
          <StyledTableCell>
            TYPE OF INTERNSHIP PROGRAM ACTIVITY
          </StyledTableCell>
          <StyledTableCell>HTE/ OFFICES</StyledTableCell>
          <StyledTableCell>COORIDNATOR/ OFFICER IN-CHARGE</StyledTableCell>
          <StyledTableCell>
            INTERN'S ROLES, DUTIES/ RESPONSIBILITIES
          </StyledTableCell>
          <StyledTableCell>COORDINATOR'S CONTACT NUMBER</StyledTableCell>
          <StyledTableCell>COORDINATOR'S EMAIL ADDRESS</StyledTableCell>
          <StyledTableCell>NO. OF HOURS</StyledTableCell>
        </TableRow>
      </TableHead>
      <TableBody>
        <StyledTableRow>
          <StyledTableCell component="th" scope="row">
            Pre-internship Activity
          </StyledTableCell>
          <StyledTableCell>
            Bulacan State University - Bustos Campus
          </StyledTableCell>
          <StyledTableCell>{"Lyn M. Dalisaymo"}</StyledTableCell>
          <StyledTableCell>
            <ul>
              <li>Compilation of credentials/ requirements</li>
              <li>
                Pre-internship orientation prior to deployment to internship
              </li>
              <li>
                Parents Virtual SIP Orientation Program of the College.
              </li>
            </ul>
          </StyledTableCell>
          <StyledTableCell>{"09451606406"}</StyledTableCell>
          <StyledTableCell>{"lyn.dalisaymo@bulsu.edu.ph"}</StyledTableCell>
          <StyledTableCell>
            <ul>
              <li>4</li>
              <li>8</li>
              <li>4</li>
            </ul>
          </StyledTableCell>
        </StyledTableRow>
      </TableBody>
    </Table>
  </TableContainer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use colSpan and rowSpan property to divide the head of table into 2 rows and the body of table into 3 rows :

```
    <table style={{ width: "100%" }}>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td rowSpan={2}>TYPE OF INTERNSHIP PROGRAM ACTIVITY</td>
          <td rowSpan={2}>HTE/ OFFICES</td>
          <td rowSpan={2}>COORIDNATOR/ OFFICER IN-CHARGE</td>
          <td rowSpan={2}>INTERN'S ROLES, DUTIES/ RESPONSIBILITIES</td>
          <td colSpan={2}>COORDINATOR'S INFO</td>
          <td rowSpan={2}>NO. OF HOURS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>CONTACT NUMBER</td>
          <td>EMAIL ADDRESS</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td rowSpan={3}>Pre-internship Activity</td>
          <td rowSpan={3}>Bulacan State University - Bustos Campus</td>
          <td rowSpan={3}>Lyn M. Dalisaymo</td>
          <td>Compilation of credentials/ requirements</td>
          <td rowSpan={3}>09451606406</td>
          <td rowSpan={3}>lyn.dalisaymo@bulsu.edu.ph</td>
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Pre-internship orientation prior to deployment to internship</td>
          <td>8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Parents Virtual SIP Orientation Program of the College.</td>
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```